# When can we NOT specify type parameter

Tags: scala

Given the following test case, there are 3 scenarios in it. I would ask what's the rules here that govern when we must and when we don't have to specify the type parameter

```
  @Test
  def testTypeParamter(): Unit = {

    class Cat[A]

    //1. Don't need to specify the type parameter for Cat
    def getCat() = new Cat
    println(getCat())

    import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

    //2. Don't need to specify the type parameter for ArrayBuffer

    val bf = new ArrayBuffer()
    println(bf)

    //3. Do need to specify the type parameter for ArrayBuffer to make bf2 += 1 work
    val bf2 = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    bf2 += 1

    println(getCat())
  }
```

Compared with #2 and #3, what can we do if we create an empty ArrayBuffer without type parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check in REPL,

**1.1 scenario without a type param**

```
scala> class Bag[A]
defined class Bag

scala> def createBag = new Bag
createBag: Bag[Nothing]
```

**1.2 ArrayBuffer[T] without type param**

```
scala>  val buffer = new ArrayBuffer()
buffer: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Nothing] = ArrayBuffer()
```

In both case you see the default type parameter as `scala.Nothing`. `scala.Nothing` is abstract and can not be instantiated which means you can't operate on your generics instance like 
`buffer+=new String("apple")` etc because `Nothing` is at the bottom of [scala class hierarchy](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/Nothing.html).

**2. providing type parameter**

This is obviously the purpose of having generic type that you want Generics for certain type.

```
scala> var buffer = new ArrayBuffer[Long]()
buffer: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Long] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> buffer+=89l
res0: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Long] = ArrayBuffer(89)
```

Comment: Thanks @prayagupd for the helpful answer. the REPL is a good tool, but I forgot it..

Comment: Yep, scala REPL or clojure REPL are very important tools to try things out quickly. And regarding when you can use `Generics[Nothing]`, I don't think you would ever want to use that, instead use `Option[Generics[T]]`. And by the way [`None`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.0/scala/None$object.html) already extends `Option[Nothing]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the type parameter when Scala infers *the type you want*. This inference is based both on arguments to method/constructor (none in your case) and on expected type (none in your case). You could also have e.g.

```
val buffer: ArrayBuffer[Long] = new ArrayBuffer()
```